# Azure Activity Log - CreatedBy Tag

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I try to get the first 'Caller' log entry, so i can get the user that created the resource group/resource and tag it with that name. But sometimes it gets a false/different caller. has anybody used the Get-AzLog command for such things and can ellaborate on that? Please ask questions if anything isn't clear

```
$log = Get-AzActivityLog -ResourceGroupName rg-pf-functions -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime
            $owner = $log[-1] | Select -ExpandProperty Caller | Group-Object | Sort-Object | Select -ExpandProperty Name
            Update-AzTag -Tag @{"createdBy"=$owner} -ResourceId $rg.ResourceId -Operation Merge
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [-maxrecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azactivitylog?view=azps-9.7.0#-maxrecord) flag with the `Get-AzActivityLog` PowerShell command to receive the first 'Caller' log entry. It returns the number of records requested by the user.

***I tried the below script by setting MaxRecord flag to 1 and it worked as expected.***

```
$logs = Get-AzActivityLog -ResourceGroupName <Resourcegroup> -StartTime 2023-04-01T10:30 -EndTime 2023-04-14T11:30 -MaxRecord 1
$owner = $logs.caller
Update-AzTag -Tag @{"createdBy"=$owner} -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup>" -Operation Merge
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

***Tags updated in the resource group as shown:***

[image]